# What could cause successful FTP transfers to be truncated on a brand new RackSpace SSD server?

Tags: windows, ftp, filezilla, rackspace, solid-state-drive

I am trying to upgrade my web server. I have created a brand new instance of a latest generation virtual server on RackSpace that uses an SSD. On this brand new instance, I installed the following:

1. Google Chrome
2. FileZilla FTP Client

I then connected to a FileZilla FTP Server on a different server, which is hosting 2 image files that I am using to test. I then downloaded the 2 image files, which FileZilla reports as "successfully transferred". However, both of the image files are truncated! What could possibly be causing this?

[image: Incorrect file size after transfer]

A few things to note:

- This only happens on the new instance if it is using an SSD. If I create an identical instance without the SSD (using SATA instead), the error does not occur.
- On the server which is transferring the files, the files are also reported as having been transferred successfully. This server has been used as an FTP server for quite some time without any issues.
- If I set up the new SSD instance as an FTP server and upload a bunch of files to it, some of them randomly get truncated by 2-10KB. Out of a ~150MB upload, I may end up with 150-200KB missing. If I transfer them again, a different subset of files gets truncated.
- If I throttle the transfer speed on the FTP server to 100KB/s, the 2 image files transfer successfully without getting truncated. If I throttle the transfer speed to 500KB/s, the image files get truncated the same way as if there was no throttling.

Any ideas on how this could be happening?

Update: It is not related to FileZilla. Here is the same issue using ftp on the command line:

[image: Incorrect filesizes]

Comment: Nasty! I would try doing the FTP by hand from the command line and see if I could rule out FileZilla. I would also try doing PUTs as well as GETs to see if the direction makes a difference. You will have to narrow this issue down somehow...

Comment: For the third bullet point above (random files getting truncated when I'm uploading to the new server), this issue occurs regardless of the particular FTP server I have running on the new instance (I have tried both FileZilla and IIS' FTP).

Comment: It sounds pretty fundamentally stuffed. Can you ssh into the server and run a script that continually creates random size files and then tests they are the correct length?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Do you mean creating files locally on the server just to test to make sure the hard drive is working? It seems that the hard drive is working fine (I was able to get a SQL database up and running and it has passed all tests). In addition, if I host the 2 image files and download them over HTTP, they download properly. The issue seems to be only with FTP

Comment: An addition to the issue. If I disable TCP Offload Checksum on the Network adapter, then the image files can transfer successfully. This however causes a new issue, in that transfer speeds now range from 0-3KB/s. speedtest.net can't even get a reading because it's less than 0.01mbps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is documented here: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/disabling-tcp-offloading-in-windows-server-2012

That article is for Windows Server 2012. In my case, I was using Windows Server 2008. To get to the network adapter properties, go to

1. Right click on Computer --> Properties
2. Device Manager
3. Open up network adapters drop down and right click --> Properties
4. Go to Advanced tab
5. Disable everything except UDP Checksum Offload.

Important note: If only some of the options are disabled, you will notice a massive performance degradation. Performance will go back up to normal levels after you have disabled all of the necessary options.

Comment: you should explain _why_ TCP offloading can cause errors like this.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea why it was happening. I arrived at this fix with help from Rackspace support.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it says that the transfer is complete is because closing the socket is- unfortunately- how FTP defines a completed transfer. (It opens up a data connection and sends the data. Closing the connection means the file is completely sent.)

For some reason, it seems like the connection is prematurely closing.

Personally, to me this does sound really bizarre and it might be a driver problem or hardware problem, but I would try:
1. Try Passive mode FTP. The command line client uses PORT mode by default. PASV is more firewall friendly.
2. Try disabling all software firewalls (like Windows Firewall) and retrying.